# Как сжать по высоте flex элемент с подтягиванием остальных элементов?

Tags: html, css

Тут еще важен порядок элементов в html и сохранить адаптивность с подстроением этого порядка

```
content-image -> content-right -> content-desc -> content-info
```

```css
.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.content > div {
  border: 1px solid #333;
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 2px;
}
.content-image {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}
.content-right {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
.content-desc {
  flex: 0 0 60%;
}
.content-info {
  flex: 0 0 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="content-image">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="content-right">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</div>
  <div class="content-desc">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</div>
  <div class="content-info">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.</div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То, что Вы хотите получить, называется masonry. Просто так на flex без "костылей" и танцев с бубном такое не сделать. Можете погуглить варианты решений или воспользоваться js-библиотекой

Comment: @humster_spb а на простом css никак? в гугле на одних костелях предлагают решение, не ужели в 21 веке до сих пор нет решения? вроде задачка простая и как я вижу по запросам зараспрастраненная) это же обычный html

Comment: ну, вот пока без "костылей" никак, увы